# Apache / Linux - .htaccess how to get specific variable from a query / url and apply to rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rule that works for one "direction" but, not the other.

A typical incoming url / query would be: (long url)

`http://somedomain.com/getme.pl?dothis=display&partnum=1234567` (could be up to 9 digits)

I have this rule in place in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)$ /getme.pl?dothis=display&partnum=$1 [L]
```

Which works great for a bit of ease getting one of the unique part numbers:

```
http://somedomain.com/1234567.
```

However, I would like to make the long url "pretty" so, I assumed I could reverse(ish) it.

So, when a link on the site is clicked on (the long url) the htaccess file would process the long url to the beautified version.

I tried MANY attempts. 
Here was my latest failure.

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)$ /getme.pl?dothis=display&partnum=$1 [L] #(works)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^partnum=([0-9]*) #(tried to get partnum)
RewriteRule ^.* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R] #(make the short url)
RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)$ /getme.pl?dothis=display&partnum=$1 [L] #(the known working rule)
```

I have tried a plethora of rules and visited many sites for advice.
I tried with just rules, just conditions and variations of query_string.

So, I believe I must just grab the "partnum" from the query and rewrite to /1234567 or http_host/1234567

Then, allow the other rule (works) to process.

So BOTH:

```
http://somedomain.com/getme.pl?dothis=display&partnum=1234567
```

and

```
http://somedomain.com/1234567
```

Display as: `http://somedomain.com/1234567` in the browser.

and both passed the whole query to the `getme.pl` script properly.

I found some close answers here but, none that really explained what I needed.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sounds of it, this should get you moving down the right path:

```
# Your working rewrite, with extra param on the rewrite
RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)$ /getme.pl?dothis=display&partnum=$1&rewrite [L]

# Redirect for long urls, to pretty url
# -The appended '&rewrite' on the first rule will force this not to match
# -The trailing '?' on the rewrite will strip the query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} partnum=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /%1? [L,R=301]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Worked well! Thank you. I do find it odd that I actually need to "fool" the rewrite to make it work but, IT DOES! Thanks again!

Comment: Good to hear! Yea, mod_rewrite makes it kind of confusing, but since it uses an internal redirect for the first rule, the rules are applied once again for that redirect.

Comment: Based on what I learned here, I tried also to REWRITE http://somedomain.com/difrent.php?notsame=1234567 to just /1234567 or to my http://somedomain.com/getme.pl?dothis=display&partnum=1234567 version as we did above. (placing the /1234567 before the rules above). I FAILED!! HELP!