# htaccess - Rewrite rule and/or condition to fix totally different discontinued or incorrect incoming link

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, conditional-statements, rule

Well, I am stuck again. Two days of reading and again, found some close solutions but, nothing fits and all my experiments failed.

This is a continuation of my question:
[here at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749753/apache-linux-htaccess-how-to-get-specific-variable-from-a-query-url-and-ap)

The 4 rules below take my incoming links:

```
  http://somedomain.com/getme.pl?dothis=display&partnum=1234567
```

and beatifies it.
Also allows users to use the beatified version right in address bar:

```
http://somedomain.com/1234567
```

Here are my working rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([\s]*)$ /getme.pl [L] ## in case there is a space or nothing.
RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)$ /getme.pl?dothis=display&partnum=$1&rewrite [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} partnum=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /%1? [L,R=301]
```

Works great but, I discovered there are some old links to the site out there:

```
http://somedomain.com/oldversion.php?id=123456789
```

And

```
http://somedomain.com/oldversion.php?r=86this&id=123456789
```

I would like to just grab the id=[0-9] and integrate it with my working rules.
I suppose, the rule would be inserted between the second and third rules above.

I tried various attempts (about 100!) like:

```
RewriteRule ^(oldversion\.php)?([a-z]{1})=([a-z0-9]*)&([a-z]{2})=([0-9]*)$ /$4? [L]

RewriteRule ^(oldversion\.php)?([a-z]{2})=([0-9]*)$ /$3? [L]
```

As you see, two days of reading and nothing is sinking in for me.
I tried several variations of the working rules I already have as well, to no avail.

Can't I just get the 123456789 off of the outdated .php urls somehow and stick it in my existing rules?

Thanks for your help and explaining down to my level co, I just might be able to understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this at the end of your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([^&]+)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^oldversion\.php$ /%1? [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

For a URI of `/oldversion.php?r=86this&id=123456789` it will **internally redirect** to `/123456789`

Remember RewriteRule just matches your URI and it cannot match your QUERY_STRING.

Comment: Thank you! What is the `|` for? Does that part, basically, either allow more in the url or (`|`) just end?

Comment: `(&|$)` means parameter id followed by `&` or end of text `$`. Also I have tested again your combined .htaccess in my apache installation and it is working fine.

Comment: @anubhava That is how I have it as well. But, the `http://somedomain.com/oldversion.php?r=86this&id=123456789` and  `http://somedomain.com/oldversion.php?id=123456789` are not "getting" to `http://somedomain.com/1234567` or actually `http://somedomain.com/getme.pl?dothis=display&partnum=123456789`. The partnum is not getting there as well. I can't figure it out. ;-(

Comment: Its really bizarre. Are you sure this .htaccess is being read? Can you put some junk text at the top and see if it generated 500 error or not. If it does show 500 error then I would need relevant lines of your access.log to start debugging this.

Comment: Yes, being read because the rewrite from the long url is being beautified and I can also use the somedomain.com/123456789 version in the address bar. Also, when the old php links are used, the default index page is served but, address bar still shows the old php address. I am going to try a test htaccess with just your rules next. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @anubhava GOT IT! Higher up I had denied access to several file types including |php|! Now, I have re-arrange a little but, THANK YOU!